# Cannot coerce String to DatetTme in Mule 4

Tags: mule, dataweave, mule4

I need to transform this String : `"2022-04-01T09:56:17.674+00:00"` to DateTime in order to send to Salesforce.

I've tried like this :
`StartDateTime: payload.planDate as DateTime {format: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"}` and instead of "DateTime", "LocalDateTime". None of them seem to work.

Both give me this error :

```
Cannot coerce String (2022-04-01T09:56:17.674+00:00) to DateTime, caused by: Text '2022-04-01T09:56:17.674+00:00'
```

Could you help me transform the String to Datetime? The expected result is all of the information inside the string.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to account for the 5 characters used in the timezone offset using `Z`, or you could use `xxx`:

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var planDate="2022-04-01T09:56:17.674+00:00"
---
{
    z: planDate as DateTime {format: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ"},
    x: planDate as DateTime {format: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSxxx"}, 
    explicit: planDate as DateTime {format: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ"} as String {format: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSxxx"}
}
```

Output:

```json
{
  "z": "2022-04-01T09:56:17.674Z",
  "x": "2022-04-01T09:56:17.674+00:00",
  "explicit": "2022-04-01T09:56:17.674+00:00"
}
```

In the last case I used `ZZZZZ` to parse the input but formatted the output explicitly by converting to a String with a format that explicitly adds the timezone offset even if it is zero.